# Regex to match if string contains integer/decimal with digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a regex that allows an integer number, or a decimal number with 0 - 2 decimal digits.

Valid Input

```
1
1.
1.1
1.11
111111111
111111111.
111111111.1
111111111.11
```

Invalid Input

```
a
a.
1.a
1.111
1.1111
```

- string allows any number of digit characters, but only allows 1 decimal/period
- if a period/decimal exists: only allow 2 digit characters after the decimal

Here is the regex I came up with

```
\d*\.?([\d]){0,2}
```

I am having trouble testing it to ensure it works.  I found a couple ways of testing it.  Using the `test` method which I just [used w3schools setup here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_test2).  The other way was with some javascript regular expression tester like [regexr](http://regexr.com) and [regex101](https://regex101.com).  For all of these: it appears that either my regular expression is returning false positives, or my regular expression does not work as intended.

**Question**: What regex would do what I want it to do?

Comment: That regex should be fine, though perhaps you want to include the start/end of line rules to: `^\d*\.?([\d]){0,2}$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to make sure that you check the complete string (from the first char to the last char) using `^...$`
2. The first digit should appear at least 1 time (so you want to use `+` and not `*`).

Check this example:

```js
r = /^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/
tests = ['1', '1.', '1.1', '1.11', '111111111', '111111111.', '111111111.1', '111111111.11', 'a', 'a.', '1.a', '1.111', '1.1111']
tests.forEach(function(val) {
  console.log(val, val.match(r) ? ': valid' : ': invalid');
});
```

### update

Following the comments - if you need a solution for "integer number, or a decimal number with 0 - 2 decimal digits" (like you said in the question, but **not** like the *valid input* section), you can use this:

```js
r = /^\d+(\.\d\d{0,1})?$/
console.log('1.'.match(r))

tests = ['1', '1.', '1.1', '1.11', '111111111', '111111111.', '111111111.1', '111111111.11', 'a', 'a.', '1.a', '1.111', '1.1111']
tests.forEach(function(val) {
  console.log(val, val.match(r) ? ': valid' : ': invalid');
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I think it should be a `+` and not `*` on the first `\d`.

Comment: I already deleted my answer and upvoted yours, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @DonCallisto, what is the problem with `12.`?  The OP said it's a valid input... (if it wasn't valid I would change the regex to set it as invalid...)

Comment: @Dekel where he said that?

Comment: @DonCallisto, 2nd line inside the `valid` block :)

Comment: @DonCallisto, added a regex for your comment (so if someone will need it it's here).

Comment: @Dekel thank you for your answer!  I am missing something here.  I plugged in your exact regex here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_test2  The issue is that '1' appears to return false.

Comment: @Neil, w3schools don't save your code. You can use jsfiddle.net for that

Comment: If you use the `RegExp` constructor you need to escape the `\\` chars. Check this update: https://jsfiddle.net/8w2z97tm/

Comment: oops, sorry about that, there you go

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget closing and opening in Regex, many new Regex for get it and they end up unwanted result, everything should between ^ and $, ^ is starting point of the word(digit) boundary and $ is ending point...something like below should help you, try:

```
'use strict';
var decimal = /^\d+(\.\d\d{0,2})$/, num = 111111111.11;
console.log(decimal.test(num));
```

Hope this helps...